# Wrap XML tags (insert around existing xml data) in xquery for eXist

Tags: xml, xquery, exist-db

Can anyone please help me with this xquery for eXist database. I have the following xml structure

```
<A>  
   <B>  
     <D/>  
     <D/>  
     <D/>  
     <E/>  
  </B>  
</A>
```

I'm trying to get the following structure

```
<A>  
   <B>  
    <C>  
     <D/>  
     <D/>  
     <D/>  
     <E/>   
    </C>   
  </B>  
</A>
```

How do I insert the `<C>` tag?

Thanks
--SD

Comment: I figured out a way to do this
suppose the entire xml is in a doc, say example.xml    

let $document := doc(example.xml)
update replace $document/B 
 with `<B>  
   <C>   
    <D/>  
    <D/>  
    <D/>  
    <E/>  
   </C>  
  </B>`

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, simple, very short and easy solution.

Comment: Hi there it looks to me that SDS is asking for a normal action on a eXist database... UPDATE is the answer and I really think Shilagae's answer is elegant and really appropriate... plus it separates logic from data... as it should always be...

Answer (score 1):

I can't verify, but it should be so:

```
let $x := doc('namedocument.xml')/A/B
update insert <C>$x</C> into  doc('namedocument.xml')/A/B
```

Answer (score 0):

**You don't need XQuery Update to do this kind of operations**.

This XQuery application:

```
<A>
 <B>
  <C>
  {for $n in /A/B/node()
   return $n}
  </C> 
 </B>
</A>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<A>      
  <B>
    <D/>
    <D/>
    <D/>
    <E/>
  </B>   
</A>
```

**produces exactly the wanted, correct result**:

```
<A>
   <B>
      <C>
         <D/>
         <D/>
         <D/>
         <E/>
      </C>
   </B>
</A>
```

Comment: He wants to use a xml db called eXist so he has to do an update. I suggest the following solution: `code`                                        let $x := doc('namedocument.xml')/A/B
update insert <C>$x</C> into  doc('namedocument.xml')/A/B                                          `code`

Comment: @Shilaghae: It is highly improbable that an XML DB supports just XQuery-Update and doesn't support XQuery. AFAIR, eXist existed long before XQuery-Update appeared -- so it must have already XQuery support. Therefore, this pure XQuery solution should work with eXist. Also this is simpler than using XQuery-Update. It is a great principle always to choose the simplest solution for a problem -- KISS.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev It was clear that eXistDb supports even only xquery (What should be the advantage of using a xmldb otherwise?) but as you certainly know, is a good rule separate the data from data management. Your solution is good (and faster than mine) if you supose that your output will never change, but if a day you will want to change your output you will have to find the xml file (in the database!), the stantment in it and than change the stantment instead of change a simple update.

Comment: @Shilaghae: Sorry, I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev :D okok Suppose you have the previous xml document, and after a bit of time this xml document changes as follow:`code`<A><E><F>.....</F><F>.....</F></E><E><F>..</F><F>..</F></E><E><F>..</F><F>..</F></E><B><D/><D/><D/><E/></B>   
</A>`code` In this specific case you should change the query too, for example:`code`<A>{for $n in /A/E return $n}<B><C>{for $n in /A/B/node() return $n}</C></B></A>`code`                                                      with the update you shouldn't.

Comment: @Shilaghae: Yes, and when it starts snowing one should change their clothes, too. :) Maybe, you need to walk with a space-suite all the time? More seriously, instead of trying to do the "almost impossible", one can easily solve such problems using XSLT -- hint: templates and pattern matching.

Comment: @Shilaghae: Not to mention that the XML you provided in your last comment is severely malformed and therefore meaningless... Nd your "update" also needs to be updated in case a new document doesnt have any `B` that is a child of some `A`

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev Do you prefer use an XSLT instead of using a functionality of an xml database that in every case he has to use? Probably if he has to use an xml database it isn't for a small xml document but to manage a great amount of documents. it is as if you have the possibility to use the "update" functionality of a sql database and you want at all costs run a script with many "insert". I'm inexperienced but, for me, is the solution simplest (no the fastest)

Comment: @Shilaghae: It is well-recognized in the XML community that XQuery isn't as good for some tasks in which XSLT is much better. There is even expressed willingness to be able at some points in an XQuery application to be able to call an XSLT transformation -- could be something that might appear in the next version of XQuery. Same with XSLT -- it could be best to retrieve the XML document/fragment using XQuery, then do the transformation on this document.

Comment: Ok, but I'm a bit confusing, when somebody should use an Xml db and the update functionality?

Comment: @Shilaghae: I am not competent in the area of XML DBs -- Ask this as a new question and I'm sure you'll get good answers.